# How can this error about WSO2-am 2.2.0 database be fixed?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2-am 2.2.0 with local database. I change h2 database to my local database and every table is created and works correctly. When this error happens system wasn't down and continued to work but I am still getting this error continuously.

Here is the error :

```
[2018-05-20 07:50:24,935] ERROR - JDBCReporter Error when reporting timers
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 6 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:259)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1547)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatementBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:2678)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtBatchExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:2547)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7347)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2713)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:224)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:204)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:2460)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor84.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter.JDBCReporter.reportTimers(JDBCReporter.java:389)
        at org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter.JDBCReporter.report(JDBCReporter.java:200)
        at com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter.report(ScheduledReporter.java:162)
        at com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter$1.run(ScheduledReporter.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please don't add images of error logs. Instead post the log in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a metrics DB issue. If you're not using metrics, you can disable it in `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/metrics.xml` file.

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Enabling+Metrics+and+Storage+Types

Comment: thanks but I need metrics's DB for my API's Analytics and Statistics. Without Metrics no timer data and no API Analytics I can have.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you run into this bug:
https://support.microsoft.com/de-at/help/970519/you-receive-a-the-incoming-tabular-data-stream-tds-remote-procedure-ca

There are workarounds available on that page.

Comment: tanks but it doesn't help, the problem comes from inside a 'reportTimers' method in wso2 JDBCReport file when insert a row in Metric-Timer table. I found the query and insert it myself without any error. so I can't get the problem still.